# Android ndk query

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am new to ndk part of android I just wants to know how to call two string values from the .so native library prepared.

Will I have to make separate library for each String call as same as HelloJNI sample? I was able to understand the HelloJni examples but didn't know that it will be possible to call two or more than two string values from a single .so native library.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need more than one library (of course you can, if there is an architectural justification). You can put many methods that do whatever you wish in a single file or in several files, all in a single library. If you want to use two String calls, based on the HelloJNI sample, you will simply have to define two methods, for example:

```
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI1
{
 return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI string1!  Compiled with ABI " ABI ".");
}

Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI2
{
 return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI string2!  Compiled with ABI " ABI ".");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot It worked. I wants some more knowledge about the .so files i.e. some one else having the .so file generated by me will be able to use it or not ? If yes then , is there anyway from which I can restrict the usage of .so files  by others or strangers !

Comment: Basically, the library can be used by others, but look here perhaps it will help you a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307684/copy-protection-for-android-ndk-so-shared-library